# DataGrid-like scrolling behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls, scroll

I need to implement control with header and items pane. This control should have scrolling behaviour similar to DataGrid. Header should scroll horizontally along with items, but should be fixed while vertical scrolling. How do I implement such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two ScrollViewers, not one

Here's the control layout I would use

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="HeaderScrollViewer" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid x:Name="Headers" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer">
        <Grid x:Name="Content" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

There are a few things to note to make this work correctly.

- Hide the ScrollBars on the `HeaderScrollViewer`. The ScrollViewer is only there for the functionality - the User won't actually interact with it.
- When the `ContentScrollViewer` scrolls horizontally, manually scroll the `HeaderScrollViewer` the same distance.
- Use [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) and [Grid.SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) to align your header Grid columns with your content Grid columns